# Fading Text On a Jquery Slider

Tags: jquery, animation, text, slider

My problem is this: I need to make a JQuery Image slider that resembles a flash video. I've been successful so far as I have the slider going but i can't get the text. I need the text to fade in after the image shows, similar to to how it does on this page http://absolutetileandstone.com/ . I've tried just about everything i can think of, including .animate() and .fadeIn() but have gotten nowhere. I've even added 2 sliders together and tried to sync the timing, which was impossible... Any suggestions?

Here's the demo that has a slider inside a slider http://www.trileafweb.com/absolute

Comment: Most jQuery sliders have some sort of 'transition finished' callback. Tie a `fadeIn()` into that, targeting the text you'd like to fade in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm.. how about redoing the slider since the plugin doesn't natively do the text fade.

***demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LQgw4/***

**html**

```
<div id="container">
    <div>
        <span class="one">absolute</span>
        <span class="two">hauuu~</span>
        <img src="http://lorempixum.com/250/200/abstract/1" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <span class="one">absolute</span>
        <span class="two">uguu~</span>
        <img src="http://lorempixum.com/250/200/abstract/2" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <span class="one">absolute</span>
        <span class="two">kyaa~</span>
        <img src="http://lorempixum.com/250/200/abstract/3" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <span class="one">blerg</span>
        <span class="two">abalone</span>
        <img src="http://lorempixum.com/250/200/abstract/4" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
#container img,
#container span {
    display:none;   
}

#container span.one,
#container span.two {
    color:#fff;
    font:bold 30px verdana;
    position:absolute;
    left:30px;
    top:90px;
}

#container span.two {
    left:130px;
    top:120px;
    font-size:20px; 
}
```

**jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    startSlider(0);
});

function startSlider(idx) {
    $img = $("#container div img").eq(idx);
    $span1 = $("#container div span.one").eq(idx);
    $span2 = $("#container div span.two").eq(idx);

    $img.fadeIn('slow', function() {
        $span1.delay(600).fadeIn('slow', function() {
            $span2.delay(600).fadeIn('slow', function() {
                $span1.delay(600).fadeOut();
                $span2.delay(600).fadeOut('fast', function() {
                    $img.fadeOut('slow', function() {
                        if ($("#container div img").length - 1 == idx) {
                            startSlider(0);
                        }
                        else {
                            startSlider(idx + 1);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
}
```

---

***or if you want that first text to not fade out: http://jsfiddle.net/azzWZ/***